# Event object of onSubmit is empty in Google script

Tags: debugging, logging, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I have a Google form linked to a Google sheet. In that spreadsheet I have code that have this

```
function onSubmit(e){
  Logger.log(e)    
  Logger.log("Call onSubmit")
}
```

The trigger is setup as follow

```
Project: Spreadsheet's scritp 
Deployment:Head 
Event:From spreadsheet - On form submit 
Function:onSubmit
```

So whenever I submit the form, the log shows

```
[object Object]
Call onSubmit
```

The form has many questions, not an empty form. As I read the documentation, it seems like the event object has many information. Is there something wrong with my setup?
I have resorted to read responses in the data sheets but that's not ideal. Too many things have to call and/or defined manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The logger is buggy and it is not  recommended to rely directly on what you see in the debugger.

#### Best practices:

- Always use `console` class instead of `Logger`
- Always `JSON.stringify()` anything that you're going to log:

  ```
  console.log(JSON.stringify(e));
  ```

The last one should fix your problem. `[object Object]` is  the result of calling `toString()` on a object, as the logger is incapable to displaying a object  directly.

```js
const obj = {a:1};
console.log(obj.toString());//[object Object]
console.log(JSON.stringify(obj));//'{"a":1}'
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, how do I access the content of `console.log`.

Comment: @TamLe Same way you access Logger.log. It is also available in View > Executions

Answer (score 3):

Unlike most browser debuggers, the Google apps script logger will only store basic string values. In most cases, this means that the documentation will be more useful for understanding complex values. In your case, the [event object for submit events](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#form-submit) is quite simple, with a `values` key for a simple array and a `namedValues` key for an object lookup of what was submitted.

Comment: I already read all of it. The problem is that in my log, the event shows nothing, only the variable type is `Object`.

Comment: If you are trying to log a complex object, using `JSON.stringify` first may help if it does not rely on getters and methods.